# Merge k Sorted Arrays

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, heap

Please review my answer for this interview question:
Merge k sorted arrays, using min heap.

```
import java.util.*;
public class MinHeap{    
 public static class HeapItem implements Comparable<HeapItem>{               
      int[] array;                
      int index;        // the index of current element               
      public HeapItem(int[] arr, int index) {
           array = arr;
           index = 0;
      }   
      @Override
      public int compareTo(HeapItem h){
          if(array[index] > h.array[h.index]){
              return 1;
          }else if(array[index] < h.array[h.index]){
              return -1;
          }else{
              return 0;
          }
      }
 }
 public static List<Integer> mergeArrays(int[][] arrays) {
      if (arrays == null || arrays.length == 0) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input!");
      }     
      // priority queue is heap in Java
      PriorityQueue<HeapItem> pq = new PriorityQueue<HeapItem>();             
      // add arrays to the heap
      for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
          pq.add(new HeapItem(arrays[i], 0));
      }
      List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer> ();       
      while (!pq.isEmpty()) {             
          HeapItem current = pq.remove();
          result.add(current.array[current.index]);                       
          if (current.index < current.array.length-1) {  
             pq.add(new HeapItem(current.array, current.index+1)); 
          }
     }
     return result;
 }          
 public static void main(String[] args){
     int[] arr1 = {1, 3, 5, 7};
     int[] arr2 = {2, 4, 6, 8};
     int[] arr3 = {0, 9, 10, 11};        
     System.out.println(mergeArrays(new int[][] {arr1, arr2, arr3}));
 }
}
```

Comment: Did you try running this code?

Comment: @Misha, sorry, as @JS1 mentioned, mistakenly I assigned zero to index. If replace `index = 0;` by `this.index = index;` it works. I'll edit it.

Comment: What about reducing merge over the array of sorted arrays? It looks simpler to me

Comment: @Caridorc How we can merge k arrays? Using stack or queue or some data structure, you mean?

Comment: Reducing means applying the function repeadeatly with two args, an accumulator and a new value. Merging k arrays may be `arrays.reduce(merge)`. While simpler I fear time complexity may be worse

Comment: Reducing / folding / injecting: https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)&ved=0CB8QFjABahUKEwjsgPCTrq3HAhVJXBoKHcstAFo&usg=AFQjCNE-XHEMaw4J_C9UU1KZOZiR4dulow&sig2=etZnYL0nHgr6kl4qUksySg

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 6):

## Bug

This might be a typo, but when I ran your program it infinitely looped.  The problem was in your constructor:

> ```
>   public HeapItem(int[] arr, int index) {
>        array = arr;
>        index = 0;
>   }
> ```

Here, you are setting `index` to 0 when you should be setting it to the input argument, like this:

```
  public HeapItem(int[] arr, int index) {
       array = arr;
       this.index = index;
  }
```

## Reuse HeapItem

Your code all seemed very reasonable to me.  There is just one small improvement I would make here:

> ```
>       if (current.index < current.array.length-1) {  
>          pq.add(new HeapItem(current.array, current.index+1)); 
>       }
> ```

I would just reuse `current` instead of creating a new `HeapItem`, like this:

```
      if (current.index < current.array.length-1) {
         current.index++;
         pq.add(current); 
      }
```

## Create result list with exact size

One other small thing you could do is compute the output list size, when you are iterating through the arrays.  That way, you could create `result` with the correct size instead of having it autoexpand as you add elements to it.

```
  int outputSize = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
      pq.add(new HeapItem(arrays[i], 0));
      outputSize += arrays[i].length;
  }
  List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer> (outputSize);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I also edited that bug you have mentioned :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest implementing merging an array of arrays as reducing merge over them. The implementation will be substantially simpler than yours but I fear time complexity may be worse.